# When can't you change the order of integration?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Apparently there are integrals which you can express as $\int_A \int_B f(x, y) \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}y$ but not $\int_C \int_D f(x, y) \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}y \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x$. When would this be the case? Is it to do with their limits not being invertible functions?

Comment: See Fubini's theorem. Most treatment include (or at least should include) a counterexample when its hypotheses fail.

Comment: See also the list of related questions on this page.

Answer (score 5):

There are pathological examples when the integral of the absolute value of $f$ over the whole space 
diverges. For instance, the example given in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245913/why-does-fubinis-theorem-not-hold-apply-to-this-function): if  $$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} e^{y-x}, & x > y \geq 0 \\ -e^{x-y}, & 0 \leq x \leq y \end{cases}$$
then
$$ \int_0^\infty \left( \int_0^\infty f(x,y) \, dx \right) dy = 1$$
but
$$ \int_0^\infty \left( \int_0^\infty f(x,y) \, dy \right) dx = -1.$$
The theorem used to determine whether you can switch the order of integration is [Fubini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem), which gives the condition that $\int_X\lvert f\rvert$ must converge, where $X$ is the whole space (in this case, $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: I meant something slightly different: when you can express the integral as dy dx in the first place, rather than whether the two integrals are not equal.

Comment: That is indeed slightly different. I don't know any cases offhand where one order of integration converges to the proper value but not the other, so I don't know that I can help. Fubini's theorem only deals with whether *both* orders converge, as far as I know.

Comment: Do you know of an example in which the limits of integration are finite?